# Android Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

Tags: android

i have created a program for selecting the date using OnDateListner method.I have completed the program but it shows a syntax error.I have crated an Xmlfile by placing the button   On button click a DatePickerDialog appears from which you can select a date.After making the selection, and clicking the Done button, a toast will appear with the selected date.
the coresponding code is being attached .

The error is shown when i am trying to close OnClickListner method

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Declaring a button and the DatePickerDialog
    private Button btnDatePicker;
    DatePickerDialog _date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //Setting an OnclickListener on the Button
        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListner(){

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //Creating an object of DatePickerDialog incontext of the Mainactivity
            //dateCallback is called which defined below
            _date=new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, dateCallback, 2012, 10, 12);

    //Showing the DatePickerDialog
        _date.show();
        }
        });

        //Setting OnDateSetListener on the DatePickerDialog

        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateCallback = new OnDateSetListener() 
        {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The date is : " + dayOfMonth+"/"+  ++monthOfYear +"/"+  year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
```

Comment: check whether you need to end your Activity with the "}" . It is pretty clear what the error is telling you. Somewhere in you java class, there is a "{" which has not been close. Could be for a listener, activity or another method.

Comment: So you should insert one `}` to your code.

Answer (score 2):

Below is your complete class.  You were not closing onCreate Method of Activity. Every method must starts with a starting brace `{`and must close with a closing brace `}`.

```
import junit.framework.Test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Declaring a button and the DatePickerDialog
    private Button btnDatePicker;
    DatePickerDialog _date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // Setting an OnclickListener on the Button
        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Creating an object of DatePickerDialog incontext of the
                // Mainactivity
                // dateCallback is called which defined below
                _date = new DatePickerDialog(Test.this, dateCallback, 2012, 10,
                        12);

                // Showing the DatePickerDialog
                _date.show();
            }
        });

    }

    // Setting OnDateSetListener on the DatePickerDialog

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateCallback = new OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    "The date is : " + dayOfMonth + "/" + ++monthOfYear + "/"
                            + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Declaring a button and the DatePickerDialog
    private Button btnDatePicker;
    DatePickerDialog _date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //Setting an OnclickListener on the Button
        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListner(){

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //Creating an object of DatePickerDialog incontext of the Mainactivity
            //dateCallback is called which defined below
            _date=new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, dateCallback, 2012, 10, 12);

    //Showing the DatePickerDialog
        _date.show();
        }
        });
}
        //Setting OnDateSetListener on the DatePickerDialog

        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateCallback = new OnDateSetListener() 
        {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The date is : " + dayOfMonth+"/"+  ++monthOfYear +"/"+  year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
```

Comment: I edited the answer.. you are missing the a brace here

   _date.show();
        }
        });
}// this one ...........